# Coverage of overlapping segments with R

Tags: r

I have this data frame:

```
example_data <- data.frame(Start = c(1,10,25, 40, 2, 11, 27, 50),
           End = c(9, 26, 30, 41, 14, 16, 40, 55),
           Group = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'))
```

| Start | End | Group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | A |
| 10 | 26 | A |
| 25 | 30 | A |
| 40 | 41 | A |
| 2 | 14 | B |
| 11 | 16 | B |
| 27 | 40 | B |
| 50 | 55 | B |

I want to know the length or coverage of each group, considering that some rows overlap with each other. For example, the second row ends at 26, and the third one starts at 25. So there is an overlap of one unit.

This would be the result that I would like to achieve:

| Group | Coverage |
| --- | --- |
| A | 29 |
| B | 32 |

I have tried this, which only works if there are no overlaps.

```
example_data %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    summarise(coverage = sum(End - Start))
```

But I have no idea how to deal with overlapping segments. Any clues?

Comment: Can there be mulitple overlaps, e.g. 2-10, 3-11 and 4-12? Also, can there be other values than integers?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple overlaps in my real dataset. And no, only integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code explanation-

- `group_by` is self-explanatory
- `pmax` is vectorised version of max (parallel maxima).  It  will return a vector of same length instead of vector of length one (as in case of max).
- `lag` fetches us the previous value (default place argument is 1)
- thus, I am taking

  - sum of

    - difference of

      - `End`, &
      - maximum of previous value of `End` and current value of `Start`

Hope it is clear enough

and yes, by adding `.groups = 'drop'` you ungroup the group_by statement without adding another specific step of `ungroup()`

```r
library(tidyverse)

example_data <- data.frame(Start = c(1,10,25, 40, 2, 11, 27, 50),
                                 End = c(9, 26, 30, 41, 14, 16, 40, 55),
                                 Group = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'))

example_data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(Coverage = sum(End - pmax(Start,  lag(End, default = 0))), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Group Coverage
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A           29
#> 2 B           32
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Does this work if there are multiple overlaps?

Comment: And yes, I updated `dplyr` and does the job. Thanks, let me check if it works with multiple overlaps and I will accept it.

Comment: @CodingBiology, what do you mean by multiple overlaps?  Please edit your example if there can be multiple row overlap condition!  The code can be modified to accomodate that

Comment: Thanks @AnilGoyal, would you mind explaining what is the function of: `pmax`, `lag` and especially `.groups = 'drop'` ? I just want to keep improving. Thanks

Comment: @CodingBiology, I have added code explanation.  Hope that is clear enough.  Still feel free to ask any clarification(s)

Comment: Dear @AnilGoyal, thanks for the clear explanation! Much more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work with multiple overlaps, but for integers only:

```
library(purrr)

your_data %>%
  split(~Group) %>%
  map(~ .x %>%
          pmap(list) %>%
          reduce(~ union(.x, seq.int(.y$Start, .y$End - 1)), .init = NULL)) %>%
  lengths() %>%
  tibble::tibble(Group = names(.), Coverage = .)
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Group Coverage
  <chr>    <int>
1 A           29
2 B           32
```

```
# Data used:
your_data <- structure(list(Start = c(1L, 10L, 25L, 40L, 2L, 11L, 27L, 50L), End = c(9L, 26L, 30L, 41L, 14L, 16L, 40L, 55L), Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```